# ¿como cambiar el cursor blanco y negro al cursor normal en android studio?

Tags: java, android, cursor

como puedo cambiar el cursor blanco y negro, al cursor normal, vi que una solucion decia shif + 0 pero no me funciona, conocen otra solucion para poder usar el cursor normal sin tener que apretar la tecla "insert" siempre que quiera escribir o copiar alguna linea.

quite el modo lectura tambien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los diferentes colores del cursor indican los diferentes métodos de inserción, cuando pusas INSERT te pones en modo sobreescribir el siguiente carácter por el que acabas de insertar, mientras que el modo "normal" no sobreescribe. Si no tocas nunca la tecla INSERT, deberías estar siempre en el modo "normal" sin sobreescribir...

Comment: A mi me pasaba lo mismo los solucione desinstalando del visual studio code el paquete vim y me funciono.. me guie por esta pagina https://programmerclick.com/article/8634700767